# Algoritmo de ordenação não está funcionando!

Tags: python, python-3.x

"""
Organize os elementos de uma lista em ordem crescente
"""

```
#ordenação bolha

#L = [5,3,1,2,4]

L = [7,4,3,12,8]

x = 0
while x < (len(L) -1):
 if L[x] > L[x+1]:
     L[x],L[x+1] = L[x+1],L[x]

 x += 1

print(L)
```

Saída:  [4, 3, 7, 8, 12]

O algoritmo não está ordenando adequadamente. O que está faltando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente você quer implementar o BubbleSort.
Uma possível implementação do BubbleSort:

```
def bubblesort(list):
    not_sorted = True
    while not_sorted:
        not_sorted = False
        for i in range(0, len(list)-1):
            if list[i] > list[i+1]:
                not_sorted = True
                list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]

    return list

print(bubblesort([1, 3, 2, 10, 2, 4]))
```

O problema do seu algoritmo é que você está passando apenas uma vez pelo array, ou seja, você está fazendo apenas uma iteração do loop de fora do Bubblesort.

Repara que essa parte do meu código:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)-1):
    if list[i] > list[i+1]:
        not_sorted = True
        list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
```

é praticamente a mesma coisa que o seu:

```
while x < (len(L) -1):
 if L[x] > L[x+1]:
     L[x],L[x+1] = L[x+1],L[x]
```

A diferença é que você tem que fazer essa parte enquanto o array não estiver ordenado. Por isso a necessidade do loop mais de fora e da variável `not_sorted`.

Esse link aqui tem o algoritmo explicado passo-a-passo de uma forma bem bacana.
http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/animation/web/BubbleSort.html

Comment: Tentei fazer baseado no seu mas não funcionou ->  https://pastebin.com/Ku2TpTMg

Comment: Você esqueceu de incrementar o `x`.  Coloca `x = x+1` depois da linha `L[x],L[x+1] = L[x+1],L[x]`, e fora do escopo do `if`.

Comment: grato! Eu estou tentado aprender!

Comment: ainda nao funciona -> https://pastebin.com/1BgUF7Fe

Comment: para mim agora os algoritmos estão iguais!

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz assim:

```
L = [7,4,3,12,8]

x = 0
while x < (len(L)-1):

  if L[x] > L[x+1]:
    L[x],L[x+1] = L[x+1],L[x]

  a = x      
  while (L[a] < L[a-1]) and (a!=0):
    L[a], L[a-1] = L[a-1],L[a]
    a -= 1

  x += 1

print(L)
```

Esse parte do a = x e do while é para ver se em posições anteriores tem algum numero menor, e ir mudando as posições. Mas sou iniciante, então não sei se fiz do jeito adequado.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1BgUF7Fe